# How to add exclusions to managed dependencies in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

How do you exclude maven dependencies in eclipse, so that exclusions appear in dependencyManagement?
I noticed that when I try to exclude dependencies the exclusions appear in actual  not in dependencyManagement, not sure if it can be done without typing it by hand?

Comment: I always add exclusions by hand in eclipse ...

Comment: well bad, bad. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way:
Open pom.xml go to "Dependency Hierarchy" tab , right click on jar file you want to exclude and select "Exclude maven artifact". then it will appear on pom.xml also.
Another way:
Add code like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

here add excluded jar in exclusion tag.

Comment: note that this will add to dependencies, not dependencyManagement, in the first case. I want to avoid second case of adding exclusions manually especially that eclipse does not help me in that case.